# Is there a way to organize my model files so that ruby/rails doesn't get confused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, my list of models in app/models is getting kinda long, and I'd like to organize it.

but, I'm aware of Ruby/Rails' naming convention for folders / sub classes.

i.e.

```
Object::MyObject::SubObject
```

would look like this:

```
object.rb
object/
-- my_object.rb
-- my_object/
-- -- sub_object.rb
```

at least to my understanding

but, what I want to do is group classes that are related to each other or interact a lot.

Here is what I would like to do (as an example, these aren't my actual classes):

```
app/models/
-- library_item.rb     # LibraryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
-- library_items/
-- -- book.rb          # Book < LibraryItem
-- -- book/
-- -- -- page.rb       # Page < ActiveRecord::Base
-- -- -- cover.rb      # Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
-- -- magazine.rb      # Magazine < LibraryItem
-- -- magazine/
-- -- -- shiny_page.rb # ShinyPage < ActiveRecord::Base
```

is this possible?
I know it is with Java, but Ruby and Rails have a very specific way of doing things, and I haven't ever read anything much about organization of large projects.

Comment: It's not necessarily just a Rails convention, but a Ruby one as well. Folders represent a nested "namespace" for the class.

Comment: yeah, I really like that ruby does that. though, sometimes it can be counter-intuitive for organization / not wanting really huge lists of classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails to automatically find these models, the class names need to match the file path, e.g.:

```
class LibraryItem::Book::Page < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Personally I prefer to keep my model hierarchy mostly flat so I that I can just type `Page` instead of `LibraryItem::Book::Page`. You can accomplish both of these things -- a file hierarchy plus short model names -- by explicitly loading your models, perhaps in an initializer.

Comment: will that mess with their database tables? for your example, will that class still correspond to the 'pages' table?

Comment: @TheLindyHop, it should. If you have a problem with that use the `set_table_name` declaration.

Comment: just saw your edit, what do you mean by explicitly loading models in an initializer? Does that somehow remove the need to use the Prefexis on the class?

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Yes, e.g. put `load 'app/models/library_items/book/page.rb'` in an initializer, and then the `Page` model is already loaded, so Rails doesn't have to go looking for it. But then you have to maintain the initializer as you change/add models.

Comment: yeah, there are always trade offs. I think as long as I document well, it shouldn't be an issue. I'm going to talk to another dev, and see if he thinks it makes more sense the simple way (not have all the :: stuff) or having actual class paths - which technically would make semantic sense.. Is there a performance / speed difference between either method that you know of?

Comment: @TheLindyHop: pre-loading models can slow down start up. There may be a patch somewhere to make Rails recursively search the whole app/models tree for missing classes, which would be slower if more convenient.